# How do I remove Wallet from Bcoin?

Tags: blockchain, bip32-hd-wallets, full-node, javascript, bcoin

I'm playing with bcoin cli and created lots of wallets. Is there any way to remove wallet via WalletDB Api?

Comment: Unfortunately right now there's no way to remove a wallet via the API in bcoin. There is a zap endpoint but I don't think it does anything yet. If you don't care about losing other wallets, you can just delete the wallet db directory from your bcoin directory.

Answer (score 2):

As Bucko commented in August 2017:

> Unfortunately right now there's no way to remove a wallet via the API in bcoin. There is a zap endpoint but I don't think it does anything yet. If you don't care about losing other wallets, you can just delete the wallet db directory from your bcoin directory.